# TortoiseSVN with ssh fails on commit

Tags: ssh, tortoisesvn

I switched from svn to svn+ssh protocoll for a subversion server and configured TortoiseSVN (v1.95) accordingly. This works fine for "update" and "show log" and even repository browser, but when I try to do a commit I get an "authentication failed" error.
Naturally you would think it is a server issue, but it works fine on other computers. Computers where I made a fresh install and also computers that already had the repositories checked out prior to the switch to svn+ssh. It works fine everywhere except on one computer. Same putty version, same Tortoise version, same ssh key. I tried deleting the cached data in Tortoise settings, I made a complete new checkout of the projects, I even deinstalled TortoiseSVN and installed it again...nothing workes. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: I found the problem, I use pageant to store my ssh keys. I have 2 and that causes the problem. When I remove 1 it works. But this is merely a workaround. Is there a solution to make it work with 2 keys stored in pageant?